# Flash Image Uploader Issue in Firefox

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, ce-1.8.1.0

When I click on Upload Image, nothing happens in Firefox.  There are no popups and no error messages in the code inspector.  This works fine in Chrome and IE, but since last week I have been unable to add images to products in Firefox.  I am using the latest version of Firefox (32.0.2) and Flash.  I maintain five Magento sites on different servers, using versions 1.7.02 and 1.8 and they all have this issue.  Are there any workarounds or bug fixes available?